# About Weak-Direct Products being Normal Subgroups of the Direct Product

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, semidirect-product, direct-product

The theorem *(Algebra, T.Hungerford, p.60)* clearly states that:

> If $ \{ G_i \}_{i \in I} $ is a family of groups, then $ \prod_{i \in I} {^{w}G_i} $ is a normal subgroup of $ \prod_{i \in I} G_i $.
>
> **NOTE** that $ \prod ^{w} $ represents a **weak**-direct product (a temporary notation in the book to highlight the difference), and $ \prod $ is the direct product as usual.

I miss the point when I try the passage from *being subgroup* to *normal subgroup*.

(I also insist on my weak-product being **external** by preference, as internal semi-products imply by definition normality of subgroups.)

Comment: I have assumed you mean $$\prod_{i \in I} ^{s}G_i$$ in my edit. Is that correct?

Comment: I think so. It is just a notation to highlight that I meant the **semi**-direct product. It is a temporary notation in the book.

Comment: You were right to begin with, having just checked a copy of the book. Perhaps in an [edit] you could specify that it is temporary notation, as you said.

Comment: thank you. I've just edited the text. It is way better now.

Comment: I feel like some context must be missing from the question. Something like the dihedral group $C_n\rtimes C_2$ is not even a subgroup of $C_n\times C_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misquoted the book (unless you are using a different edition than what I use).  The term is ***weak direct products***, not semidirect products as you said.  Semidirect products are completely different beasts and I am not sure if the term is even defined for an arbitrary number of groups.

Weak direct products, or what some group theorists call direct sums, are defined as follows.  If you have a family $(G_i)_{i\in I}$ of groups $G_i$ where $i$ ranges over an index set $I$, then the weak direct product $G:=\prod_{i\in I}^w\,G_i$ in Hungerford's notation (sometimes written as my preferred notation $\bigoplus\limits_{i\in I}\,G_i$ or in [Wikipedia's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_groups) $\sum\limits_{i\in I}\,G_i$) consists of tuples $(g_i)_{i\in I}$ such that each $g_i\in G_i$ for all $i\in I$, and that $g_i$ is the identity of $G_i$ for all but finitely many $i\in I$.  The multiplication rule in $G$ is given by pointwise multiplication.

When $I$ is a finite set (or when $G_i$ is trivial for all but finitely many $i\in I$), then of course, the weak direct product $G=\bigoplus\limits_{i\in I}\,G_i$ and the usual direct product $\tilde{G}:=\prod\limits_{i\in I}\,G_i$ coincide.  However, in general, $G$ is a normal subgroup of $\tilde{G}$, which is always proper when there are infinitely many $i\in I$ such that $G_i$ is nontrivial.

Normality of the inclusion $G\leq \tilde{G}$ is quite easy to see.  Let $g:=(g_i)_{i\in I}\in G$ and $h:=(h_i)_{i\in I}\in\tilde{G}$.  Then,
$$hgh^{-1}=\left(h_ig_ih_i^{-1}\right)_{i\in I}\,.$$
Note that $g_i$ is the idenitity for all but finitely many $i\in I$.  Therefore,
$$h_ig_ih_i^{-1}=h_ih_i^{-1}=1$$
for such $i$.  Thus, $hgh^{-1}$ is in $G$.  Therefore, $G\trianglelefteq \tilde{G}$.

Comment: I'm pretty sorry about the confusion... That's exactly what I meant to say. But I never saw *weak products* elsewhere and in class we talked about it as if they were similar language for the same notion.